# Mysql returns ***** instead of number

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm experiencing something extraordinary with Laravel / MySQL at the moment.
I'm retrieving a text from the database (using Eloquent), and this text can contain a particular tag. This tag automatically gets replaced when it matches a particular pattern.

It looks like this: [tag-123]
The '123' is the unique identifier of this tag. 
Nothing strange here. 
However, as soon as this identifier has a length of 6 or more numbers, the tag suddenly looks like this after being retrieved: [tag-*****]
It doesn't matter if the number is six numbers or nine numbers long, it always returns five asterisks instead of the number.

What's going on here? I've never experienced something like this before.

So, in short:
When the text contains [tag-123], it returns [tag-123].
When the text contains [tag-123456], it returns [tag-*****].

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of tag name column ?

Comment: Also, how are you selecting this data, or are you viewing it raw in the db?

Comment: The type of the column is TEXT. It's being selected using Eloquent. Model::select(.....)

Comment: (on note of performance, I would use varchar or even a column pair, not text)

Comment: This field can contain more text than just the tag.

Comment: @Raaamy So, what's the size of value in that TEXT column ?

Comment: It can be between 10 and 1000 characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Model::select, DB::table('model')->select has solved this issue. I'm still confused...